# check constraint that has dynamic list

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a check constraint, the problem i face is that the list of values accepted by the constraint changes in the future (ex:now "red,green and blue" in the next month "red,green,blue and white"). How to do this ?

Comment: Perhaps making it a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to a reference table?

Comment: foreign key is not created for this

Comment: I agree with ypercube: a foreign key to a "lookup table" is what you should use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do this with a foreign key constraint.

You can create a check constraint with the following definition

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
Color varchar(10) CHECK (Color in ('red','green','blue'))
)
```

But there is [no way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of altering a check constraint definition without dropping it and recreating it (thus requiring all rows to be revalidated against the new definition)

> To modify a `CHECK` constraint, you must first delete the existing `CHECK`
>   constraint and then re-create it with the new definition.

This is trivial to do with a Foreign Key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE Colors
  (
     Color VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
  )

INSERT INTO Colors
VALUES      ('red'),
            ('green'),
            ('blue')

CREATE TABLE T
  (
     Color VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES Colors
  )
```

Though I'd probably introduce a surrogate key to the `Colors` table rather than storing the string repeatedly in the main table.

[I have come across the argument before](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/archive/2004/02/17/882.aspx) that using a check constraint is somehow "more correct" than using foreign keys and a lookup table but the advantages of the lookup table to me are.

1. Easier and more efficient to add items to the list.
2. Easier to get a distinct list of allowable colours (e.g. to display in a listbox in your application)
3. Using a fixed length integer surrogate key can have performance advantages compared to a variable length string both in terms of reducing row size and avoiding fragmentation on updates.

NB: It is possible to have a check constraint reference a scalar UDF that in turn references a table but this approach should be avoided. It does not simulate a foreign key correctly (e.g. does not validate on `DELETE FROM Colors`)

Comment: but what i find it strange is to change all my database model only for a constraint

Comment: @user2080105 - It's not exactly a huge change to the model and gives you greater flexibility and efficiency. You can stick with using a check constraint if you really want but as I say in my answer altering this will in fact require `CREATE`-ing a new constraint and will require all rows of the table to be read to validate it. Additionally if you are using a FK it is trivial to add an admin interface that allows new colours to be added as it just adds new rows to that table.

Comment: what if i ignore it ! i don't create a constraint at all

Comment: @user2080105 - Then you obviously run the risk of getting invalid data such as "fish" stored instead of an expected colour.

Comment: @user2080105: Why do you think that is strage?  It's the standard way to model such a constraint in a relational database.

Comment: @MartinSmith: SQL Server lets you create a CHECK constraint without applying it to existing rows. ([WITH NOCHECK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx))  The risks are obvious, I hope.

Comment: @Catcall - That's true. And in the case that the new constraint is just the old constraint with some additional items in the list it shouldn't cause an integrity problem (as long as the new constraint is created before the old constraint is dropped), It does mean the constraint is untrusted however and can't be used by the optimiser. e.g. For a trusted constraint `Color in ('red','green','blue')` a query on `WHERE Color = 'Purple'` wouldn't touch the table at all.

Comment: @Martin: Good point about trusting the constraint. Out of curiosity, I set up the example and found that the optimizer eagerly parameterized a simple `=` in the `WHERE` clause, and still table scanned; using `Color IN ('purple', 'black')` with a trusted constraint did indeed change the plan to a constant scan as expected.

Comment: Martin, a check constraint wrapped in a scalar UDF can also have false positives and false negatives.